# Visual Studio Data Tools 2015 with Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm strictly a BI developer (Database projects, SSIS, etc). I'd like to use Team Explorer with my [SQL Server Data Tools 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx) installation. I understand that there is not a stand-alone Team Explorer version for Visual Studio 2015. Is Microsoft really requiring us BI Devs to install the full-blown version of Visual Studio? It's awfully inconvenient..  What's the best option for people just needing Data Tools with the ability to connect to TFS?

Comment: Which edition of VS 2015 are you using?

Comment: @Cece - MSFT : Not sure why the downvote... I'm not using an edition of VS per se.. I'm just using SQL Server Data Tools 2015 which uses the VS _shell_ (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx). "If you do not have Visual Studio 2015, SSDT preview will install Visual Studio 2015 Integrated shell and Visual Studio 2015 Isolated shell with limited feature support for SQL Server Database Projects." With previous editions of Data Tools, I could just install Data Tools and then install Team Explorer separately. It appears this is no longer the case for Data Tools 2015..

Comment: Did you manage to install team explorer?

Comment: @RogierWijsman the only solution is to install the free VS Community edition which contains Team Explorer (but is over 6gb). You can't install the Team Explorer add-in by itself.

Comment: This is so annoying to install VS Full version just to use TFS features. Is it still the case or any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a stand-alone Team Explorer installer for VS 2017. I recommend going that route so as to not install a bloated Visual Studio.

"When we shipped TFS 2017 and Visual Studio 2017, we didn’t provide a “Team Explorer” like solution.  Historically our Team Explorer installer has been available for customers that want a rich client to access version control and some work item tracking features in TFS or VS Team Services.  We didn’t release it because we needed to create a new version of it based on the new Visual Studio installer technology that was introduced in VS 2017 and we just didn’t have time  to do that before we released.  Along with the release of VS 2017.1 today, we are now releasing a Team Explorer installer."

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/

Comment: How did you get this to work since newest version of SSDT is for visual studio 2015? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt Did you find a way to get the newest ssdt to work in the visual studio 2017 shell so that you could use this team explorer plugin for 2017? I can't find a team explorer plugin installer for vs 2015 anywhere.

Comment: @bpfrenchak The "standalone" Team Explorer installation is really the VS 2017 shell with just Team Explorer installed. I'm currently working by making all changes in VS 2015 SSDT, then having VS 2017 open in another window with Source Control Explorer open. It won't automatically detect when new items are added, but you can right-click the solution parent folder and click "Add Items to Folder". This will detect and try to include new items to be tracked. It's not an integrated experience, but gets the files into TFS with full history.

Comment: @bpfrenchak Not sure what you mean. Latest SSDT works fine in VS 2017 (per your link). It just doesn't include SSIS yet.

Comment: Exactly, at the beginning of your question you ask how to use this with SSIS. A BI developer needs SSRS, SSIS, and SSAS to have a complete toolset. So, your answer doesn't solve the question. Once they support SSIS in 2017 it will. The only way to currently get team viewer explorer added to ssdt with the 2015 shell is by installing something like VS web express, but I didn't put that as answer because it is still too "bloated" like you said. However it is the least bloated fully working solution. Using 2017 is not a viable answer to the question unless one doesn't need SSIS.

Comment: They released SSIS for SSDT 2017 since this post, however the TFS plugin is broken when using with SSDT 2017 http://sqlkover.com/ssdt-2017-and-tfs-integration/ so Cece Dong's answer is still the only solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try to find the package `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TeamExplorer.vsix` on another computer with already installed version of VS2015 with Team Explorer. It is about 47 Mb. Then copy it and install on the computer with the integrated shell. This approach has worked for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me: "The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Integration.ServicesPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Integration' package did not load correctly

Answer (score 2):

Just try to install SQL Server Data Tools 2015 which uses the VS shell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx), and confirmed this shell doesn't contain Team Explorer plug-in. If you want to use Visual Studio 2015, then install the free [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) will be an option.

Otherwise, you may consider using [TFS web portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998.aspx), or the supported Team Explorer version that TFS 2015 supports, like Team Explorer 2013, etc.

Comment: To clarify your answer, the shell doesn't contain the Team Explorer plugin _and_ installing Team Explorer 2013 won't add it to VS 2015 shell. This is in contrast to previous versions. The only solution is to install VS 2015 Community Edition (a minimum of extra 6GB of local disk and bunch of extra stuff I don't need).

Comment: I mean you can use Team Explorer 2013 and VS 2015 shell separately, Team Explorer 2013 won't integrate to VS 2015. But, yes, the direct way is to to install VS 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: It should be noted that the Community Edition is not licensed for Enterprises.

Comment: Can install a Visual studio express version for enterprises, and it will install the team explorer add in as well.