# Connecting VS 2015(Integrated) to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SQL Server Data Tools (which = Visual Studio 2015 (Integrated)) and I am having trouble being able to connect to TFS.  I can see the Team Explorer window, but when I click "Manage Connections" --> "Connect to Team Foundation Server" ....nothing happens.  I get no error or prompt or anything.  Has anyone else had issues like this?  Spent most of my day googling the problem yesterday and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I cannot use VS community as I am part of a company and it would violate the TOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791533/visual-studio-data-tools-2015-with-team-explorer

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, TFS is not included in the minimal VS that SSDT installs.  If you're not able to use VS Community due to license restrictions, I would suggest looking into the Express edition (Web or Desktop) of Visual Studio 2015.  It has a less restrictive license and supports the SSDT tools.